# What would be the most secure way to register a user from my Phonegap app to my DB

Tags: php, mysql, cordova

I am writing a phonegap application which I want to send ajax request and register users
with some parameters for ex: `full name`,`email`,`password`.

What would be the most secure way to build my PHP script to prevent other users from 
flooding my DB with register requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some standard methods:

- Captcha
- Add a hidden or invisible field to the form, and if any data is in it, disallow registration.
  Hidden will only catch stupid robots, as they can usually tell that that's what it is, but invisible is trickier if you do it with CSS and/or Javascript. Variations on this theme are also good, such as having a field with a timestamp in it, then comparing it to now (and denying if it's too old/from the future), or using magic values in some manner.
- Send them an email, if it bounces, disallow registration.
- Check the referral URL through `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`. If your registration page isn't on your homepage, make it so they have to come from somewhere on your site.
- Use non-dictionary words for element labels. Although this can make debugging more of a pain, it prevents bots from guessing the type of data that would be valid in the field.

Answer (score 0):

One of the approach would be to embed a SECRET_KEY in your Java file and access it through a plugin just before you make the ajax call with the Register Form. Send the SECRET_KEY along with the user registration info to verify the calls are being made from your app only. Ignore any that don't contain the SECRET_KEY.

Embedding the SECRET_KEY in your Java file is a suggestion as an .apk file can easily be "unzipped" to view the source (/www folder) but not the Java files.

"load-balancing" to handle large amounts of requests to your server api's would be a good option. If you are running IIS, there should be some modules that you can plugin to effectively utilize the incoming requests.

Comment: I'm wrapping my html5 with phonegap so I'll need to use JS for it.
anyway, if someone will have that "secret key" he could register also. 
wouldn't it be kind of easy sniffing the "secret" key? since its only a simple post/get request.

Comment: That is an added layer of protection. Use a DES/ AES to encrypt your private key. Or make an additional handshake call to the server before you submit your user registration info.

Comment: It is possible to decompile an APK file and get java classes out of it. Just like any decompiled code, it's not the easiest to read but it's there along with your "secret" key. Also DES has been rather insecure for a while.